# postgresql syntax error at or near "EXERCISE_ID" at character 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, intellij-idea

for postgres in Docker I use some .sql files to build the database. A script concatenates all files in the right order. It doesn't start the Postgres-image, because there is a syntax error. I don't see it, so maybe one of you do it?

LOG from IntelliJ:

```
2018-03-25 11:05:32.628 UTC [73] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXERCISE_ID" at character 1
2018-03-25 11:05:32.628 UTC [73] STATEMENT:  EXERCISE_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  EXERCISE_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  EXERCISE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  EXERCISE_SUBCATEGORY INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TL_CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID),
  EXERCISE_DATE_ADD DATE NOT NULL,
  EXERCISE_DATE_CHANGED DATE NOT NULL,
  EXERCISE_LOCATION_URL VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  EXERCISE_STATUS VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sqlinit.sql:47: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXERCISE_ID"
LINE 1: EXERCISE_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ^
```

.sql:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TL_EXERCISES (
     EXERCISE_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     EXERCISE_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     EXERCISE_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
     EXERCISE_SUBCATEGORY INT NOT NULL REFERENCES TL_CATEGORIES(CATEGORY_ID),
     EXERCISE_DATE_ADD DATE NOT NULL,
     EXERCISE_DATE_CHANGED DATE NOT NULL,
     EXERCISE_LOCATION_URL VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
     EXERCISE_STATUS VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
);
```

Analysis from IntelliJ did not find any errors.

I would be very happy, if you would help me.

Comment: Maybe there is a previous error in your script.

Comment: Does your PostgreSQL version support `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` syntax?

Comment: Yes, if I change that to `CREATE TABLE`, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` code works:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1f041.

Comment: txh for the link! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was, as I already thought, my big fault.
The Script concatenates the .sql-files; in one of the files was a comment in the last line. So the first line of the next line was also commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2018-03-25 11:05:32.628 UTC [73] STATEMENT:  EXERCISE_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
...
LINE 1: EXERCISE_ID SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

Somehow you seem to have lost the "CREATE TABLE" line from your sql. I've no idea how I'm afraid.